# Dynamic dropdown menu using HTML

Tags: jquery, html, dropdown

I have this code in HTML:

```html
<fieldset id="fsItem">
  <legend>Item &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button id="bAnt"><</button>
    <input type="text" class="input" id="idItem" value="0" disabled>
    <button id="bNex">></button>
    <button id="bAdd">+</button>
    <button id="bRem">&ndash;</button>
  </legend>
  <label>Item</label>
  <select>
    <option value="person">Person</option>
    <option value="vehicle">Vehicle</option>
    <option value="animal">Animal</option>
  </select>
  <p><label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="input" id="nameItem" value="" disabled>
    <p><label>Age</label>
      <input type="text" class="input" id="ageItem" value="" disabled>
      <label id="lbAs">Associate</label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="input" id="chkAs" value=""></p>
    <p><label>Details</label>
      <textarea class="input" id="detailsItem" rows=5 disabled></textarea></p>
</fieldset>
```

How can I modify fields based on the item selected from dropdown?

The default item will be "Person".

If I select "Animal" the fields "Name", "Age", "Associate" will disappear. The field "Pet Name" will appear.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/weupdxf3/)?

Comment: Exactly! How can I navigate through created itens and edit them?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are required to use javascript in this situation I believe. In your javascript file, write a function that determine what dom being selected. First, you need to set id for your "select" tag

```
            ...<select id="typeB">
                <option value="person">Person</option>
                <option value="vehicle">Vehicle</option>
                <option value="animal">Animal</option>
            </select>...
```

create div for each categories that you want disappear or reappear

```
<div id="petName">
<p><label>Pet Name</label>
<input type="text" class="input" id="nameItem" value="" display="none">
</div
```

Applied this to all others categories. Make all of the div categories's display properties equals to "none"
Finally, in your javascript file, look for user's selected item by following

```
if (document.getElementByID("typeB").value == "animal") { //if animal is being selected
   document.getElementByID("petName").style.display = "block"; // if your PetName field's id is petName
   ... // write some code that will make the rest of categories that you want to hide has display properties of "none" (same way as when you set display properties to "block".
}
```

Hope this help, thanks!

Comment: I liked the ideas. Ty!